# 2do Strigbuffer manda null

Tags: android-studio

estoy utilizando un stringbuffer que me funciona bien pero al momento de hacer otro stringbuffer para otra operacion me lo manda null quisiera saber que estoy haciendo mal ya que utilice la misma estructura del cual ya funciona.

```
private void showList(List<LineItem> list) {

    saleList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    for(LineItem line : list) {
        saleList.add(line.toMap());
    }

    SimpleAdapter sAdap;
    sAdap = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), saleList,
            R.layout.listview_lineitem, new String[]{"name","quantity","price","numProvider"},
            new int[] {R.id.name,R.id.quantity,R.id.price,R.id.numProvider});
    saleListView.setAdapter(sAdap);

    Iterator<LineItem> productosI = list.iterator();
    String[] arProd = new String[list.size()];
    String[] arProd1 = new String[list.size()];
    StringBuffer line = new StringBuffer();
    StringBuffer line2 = new StringBuffer();

    while (productosI.hasNext()) {
        for(int i =0; i<arProd.length;i++) {
            arProd[i] = productosI.next().ordernarArticulos();
        }

    }

    while (productosI.hasNext()) {
        for(int i =0; i<arProd1.length;i++) {
            arProd1[i] = productosI.next().ContenidoCompra();
        }
    }


    for(int x = 0; x<arProd.length;x++)
    {
        line = line.append(arProd[x]);
    }
    for(int y = 0; y<arProd1.length;y++)
    {
        line2 = line2.append(arProd1[y]);
    }

    for (LineItem e : list) {

        txtQR1 = e.ordenarEncabezado();
    }

    txtQR = txtQR1 + line+">";
    txtQR2 = ""+line2;
    Log.i("Contenido1",txtQR);

}
```

---

### metodos utilizados arriba

```
public String ordenarEncabezado() {
    Date horaActual = new Date();
    String hora =(horaActual.getYear()+1900)+""+(horaActual.getMonth()+1)+""+horaActual.getDate();

    return "<<TTX"+"F"+getId()+"M01"+"P"+numProvider+"D"+ hora + ">";

}

public String ordernarArticulos(){


    return "<C"+product.getBarcode()+"Q"+quantity+">";

}

public String ContenidoCompra()
{
    return getProduct()+" "+quantity+"\n";
}
```

Comment: ¿Será el llenado de `arProd1` en esta línea: `arProd1[i] = productosI.next().ContenidoCompra();`? Ahí haces una llamada a `ContenidoCompra`, debes revisar entonces si `arProd1` se está llenando bien. Y si `ContenidoCompra` es un método ten en cuenta respetar la *convención de nombres*, cualquiera que analice tu código pensará que eso es una clase, no un método.

Comment: de echo si muevo el line1 y el arprod1 a la primera posicion y el arprod y line las muevo al segundo ya me muestra lo que sare en line1 pero line me lo manda ahora null